# KineticJS Z-Index doesnt apply

Tags: canvas, z-index, kineticjs

Hi stackoverflow community

I'm trying to layer images by using KineticJS. Unfortunatly it does not work.
Like you see in the code snippet i'm setting the Z-Index of two pictures, when i log them they're still in the same order.
You can see the function `startClouds(field)`. This function creates clouds with a Z-Index of 2, what actually works. Im trying to fix that since an hour and i really have no idea why its not working.

```
var title = new Image();
var title_p = new Image();
title.src = '/test/images/title_bg.png';
title_p.src = '/test/images/title_pic.png';

title.onload = function(){
    var title_background = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: title
    });
    field.add(title_background);
    title_background.setZIndex(1);
    field.draw();
    console.log('Z-Index of background: '+title_background.getZIndex());

    var title_pic = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: title_p
    });
    field.add(title_pic);
    title_pic.setZIndex(3);
    field.draw();
    console.log('Z-Index of Title: '+title_pic.getZIndex());

    startClouds(field);

    var start = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 240,
        y: 160,
        text: '[Press Any Key to Start]',
        fontSize: 22,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fill: 'white'
    });
    field.add(start);
    field.draw();
    stage.add(field);
}
```

Thx for the help straight ahead

Comment: It would help if you put your code in a jsfiddle so people could see the console log and could play with your code.

Comment: well... wait i'll have to change the paths.

Comment: let me know if the answer below helped you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kineticjs every time you add a new image to a layer, the index is automatically set. Indexes start at 0

First, re-order your code like so:

```
 //create objects first
 var title_background = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: title
 });
 var title_pic = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: title_p
 });
 var start = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 240,
    y: 160,
    text: '[Press Any Key to Start]',
    fontSize: 22,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: 'white'
});
// now add objects to layer
field.add(title_background);   // z-index of 0
field.add(title_pic);          // z-index of 1
field.add(start);              // z-index of 2

startClouds(field);   // anything created by startClouds() is going to have z-index > 2
```

if you want to move things around z-indexes, try to avoid

```
 .setZIndex()  //note: use this AFTER all the objects have been added to the layer
```

function and use

```
 .moveToTop() and .moveToBottom() //this way the movement is relative rather than specific.
```

If you'd like more help, paste some functional code in a jsfiddle and I can help you out some more.

Comment: So i made this little fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/QKJbA/1/, your code snippet isn't really changing something :)

Comment: Well. Actually the clouds aren't important anymore. Actually i just want to change the Z-Index of the title_background and the title_pic.

Comment: What do you want the index of each to be? Always on top?

Comment: Basically, what do you want the z-index behavior of the background and title to be?

Comment: Actually i just want to change them xD It sounds so easy but it wont work!

Comment: You need to be more specific, i don't understand what xD means

Comment: I want to change the Z-Indexes of title_background and title_pic. If you still dont understand what i mean we can move this litle talk into the chat if you dont mind.

Comment: If you can't change them with the cloud timer thats because your title and background are not visible to the function, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QKJbA/2/

Comment: I would move it to that, but it says your reputation is too low

Comment: Ok it works now. You seem to like, some kind of mage. No Sirious thx.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to fix the jsFiddle which helped to resolve this question? I would really love to see it because I'm quite confused by Kinetic z-Index. The accepted answer here is full of broken links, because files like http://www.wallerdeknaller.ch/test/td_functions.js are no longer there.

I think jsFiddle works best if it is quite self-encapsulated, with all the necessary code and css wrapped inside it. Or at least, loading a library from a CDN. If you want don't want the hassle of repairing the fiddle for posterity, I'm happy to do it if you send me the files.

I'm aware this isn't following the SO answering guidelines, I just don't have the 50 reputation to comment on the correct answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi Oscar, sorry, those files were moved. But as a tip! After a half year of working with KineticJS I use the moveDown(), moveUp(), moveToBottom() and moveToTop() methods. It has worked better then setting the Z-Indexes. Somehow i didnt get that working by setting absolute Z-Indexes. If you have any questions dont mind Messaging me.